# How to show progress bar when uploading a file in android retrofit

Tags: java, android, http-post, retrofit, retrofit2

I am developing an android app using retrofit. I want to upload any type of file to my server with parameters. For example in my app there is text field like email and file upload field. when i entered the fields and click the submit button. It shows the percentage of uploading file and send the file and data to server. when the uploading process going it want to shows the percentage of completed file. How it possible? 
Did any reference site or tutorial?
Please help me?

Answer (score 1):

create this interface

```
public interface ProgressListener {
                void transferred(long num);
            }
```

And this class

```
    public class CountingTypedFile extends TypedFile {

        private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

        private final ProgressListener listener;

        public CountingTypedFile(String mimeType, File file, ProgressListener listener) {
            super(mimeType, file);
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(super.file());
            long total = 0;

            try {

                int read;
                while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                    total += read;
                    out.write(buffer, 0, read);

                    try{
                        if (this.listener != null)
                            this.listener.transferred(total);
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }

                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Define this method

```
@POST("/{path}")
    public JsonObject makeRequestForAttachmentsUpload(@Path(value = "path", encode = false) String path, @Body MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput);
```

then call upload method like this

```
    RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
    ApiService apiService = restClient.getApiService();

MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput = new MultipartTypedOutput();
    // add and string parameters            
    for (String key : requestParams.keySet()) {
                    multipartTypedOutput.addPart(key, new TypedString(requestParams.get(key)));
                }

    // add attchments
                multipartTypedOutput.addPart(attachmentName, new CountingTypedFile(attachmentType, new File(attachmentPath), listener));
apiService.makeRequestForAttachmentsUpload(requestName, multipartTypedOutput);
```

and listen for progress by defining this listener

```
listener = new DPAPIService.ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void transferred(long num) {
                    publishProgress(((num / (float) fileSize)));
                }
        };
```

Comment: Thank you Shabir. I am new to retrofit. So can you tell me what is the gradle code of android studio.

Comment: You can read all the details here

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-upgrade-guide-from-1-9

Comment: @shabir Your code is using old retrofit. The TypedFile is not supporting new retrofit. I want new retrofit code.